# .NET Core EF Migration via VSTS

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, azure-devops

When I try to build a migration script locally on my machine, it works fine. However, in VSTS Build, I get a strange exception:

```
**Exception message:**
The migration 'ΓÇôp' was not found.

**Verbose Log:**
dotnet exec --depsfile D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.runtimeconfig.json "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\DotnetTools\dotnet-ef\2.1.0-rc1-final\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" migrations script -p ..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj -o D:\a\1\a\Migrations\migration.sql -i --assembly D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.dll --startup-assembly D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.dll --project-dir D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\ --language C# --working-dir D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth --verbose --root-namespace Company.A...
Using assembly 'Company.API.Auth'.
Using startup assembly 'Company.API.Auth'.
Using application base 'D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0'.
Using working directory 'D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth'.
Using root namespace 'Company.API.Auth'.
Using project directory 'D:\a\1\s\Company.API.Auth\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding BuildWebHost method...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from BuildWebHost method on 'Program'.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'ApplicationContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Company.API.Auth'...
No design-time services were found.
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration 'ΓÇôp' was not found.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsAssemblyExtensions.GetMigrationId(IMigrationsAssembly assembly, String nameOrId)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateScript(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.ScriptMigration(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScriptMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The migration 'ΓÇôp' was not found.
Process completed with exit code 1.
```

If I try the same on my local machine, it works fine:

```
C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth>dotnet ef migrations script -p ..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj -o %TEMP%\script.sql -i -v
Using project '..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj'.
Using startup project 'C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth.csproj'.
Writing '..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\obj\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\glen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF618.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo ..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj
Writing 'C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\obj\Company.API.Auth.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\glen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF7ED.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth.csproj
dotnet build C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.86
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\glen\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\glen\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet\2.0.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll migrations script -o C:\Users\glen\AppData\Local\Temp\script.sql -i --assembly C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.BaseClassLibrary.dll --startup-assembly C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0\Company.API.Auth.dll --project-dir C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.BaseClassLibrary\ --verbose --root-namespace Company.BaseClassLibrary
Using assembly 'Company.BaseClassLibrary'.
Using startup assembly 'Company.API.Auth'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\netcoreapp2.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth'.
Using root namespace 'Company.BaseClassLibrary'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\glen\source\repos\Company\Company.API.Auth\Company.API.Auth\Company.BaseClassLibrary\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding BuildWebHost method...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from BuildWebHost method on 'Program'.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'ApplicationContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Company.API.Auth'...
No design-time services were found.
Writing 'C:\Users\glen\AppData\Local\Temp\script.sql'...
```

The VSTS Command Line is as follows and runs within the working directory for my WebAPI project:

```
dotnet ef migrations script –p ..\Company.BaseClassLibrary\Company.BaseClassLibrary.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Migrations\migration.sql -i -v
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using one of the hosted agent options? If so, which one? Are you or anyone else contributing to the project using a non-English locale? I'm wondering if there's some UTF shenanigans happening.

Comment: Also, if possible, pare things down to the point where you can isolate the cause to some degree. That might be enough to find a solution.

Comment: Nope, there shouldn't be any other locales in use, I've had a look through and can't find anything obvious. I did think I needed to make things simple so that's why I tried it locally...I had hoped it would fail there too, but it didn't!

Comment: I'm using the standard Hosted 2017 build agent and .NET Core 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using Command Line 2.x in VSTS rather than the default 1.x